# How to reference an object from SSRS's Code pane?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

How to reference an object from Code(After of Page Setup, before References) ?

For example, given this class:

[image]

How can I use that object in Code pane, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Public Shared Function Test() As String

    Test = "Hello " & m_Class1.SomeFunction()

End Function
```

I tried this too, not working too:

```
Public Shared Function Test() As String

    Test = "Hello " & Code.m_Class1.SomeFunction()

End Function
```

Note, I don't have the assembly's source code, I cannot make my changes directly there

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't. 
Whatever you write in the Code pane has to be static (Shared in vb), so you should wrap your "ClassLibrary2.Class1" in a static method and call it like `ClassLibrary2.MyStaticClass.MyStaticMethod()` (or in a new assembly, given that you can't recompile the original one)

Note that indeed you can call your instance m_Class1 instance from within the expression box of RS items like Code.m_Class1.SomeMethod()

Comment: If that indeed is true, that's uncool of Microsoft. you can call the component from expression but you can't call it in Code

Comment: It seems that the Code pane it's just code compiled into a static class, while the instance class belongs to the report instance. Have you tried to instantiate the class in the code panel ? i.e. ClassLibrary2.Class1 myInstance = new ClassLibrary2.Class1() ?

Comment: yep, I already tried that, but it can't see the class despite the fully-qualified name